# How to fix "error `/' not found" error about jekyll in localhost:4000

Tags: jekyll, blogs

When I run `jekyll serve`, I open the site localhost:4000 in the browser. Partial pages shows 404. And the serve indicates the error "error `/' not found" .
But when open the site use 'https://username.github.io', it's just be all normal.
It's completely confused.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UDHkQ.png)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change the param "baseurl" in your "_config.yml" to a path where you expect your site to be served or comment the line of "baseurl" to allow '/' 
 to used instead.

Comment: Setting the value of the baseurl to an empty string - **baseurl: ""**  worked. 
Equally, commenting out the entire line also did the job - **#baseurl: ""**